# Docker permission denied when writing files inside container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I'm trying to download a PDF and save it inside my application which is dockerized. The problem seems to be that I'm not allowed to write files inside the container. Here are the steps I took:

I first created a named volume `myvol`: `docker volume create myvol`. I then updated my `docker-compose.yml` file as follows:

```
version: "3"
services:
        webpp:
                container_name: webapp
                image: webapp:latest
                build: .
                ports:
                        - "8000:8000"
                volumes:
                        - myvol:/app

volumes:
        myvol:
```

And for reference, my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.7

WORKDIR /app
ADD ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . .
RUN groupadd -g 999 appuser && \
        useradd -r -d /app -u 999 -g appuser appuser
RUN chown -R appuser:appuser /app

USER appuser
RUN mkdir webapp/_tmp; chmod a+rwx webapp/_tmp/

EXPOSE 8000
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "main.py"]
```

When I run my code, I get a permission denied. The same happens if I `exec` into the container and try to write something, or for example `wget http://duck.com` also gives me a Permission denied error.

I'm unsure what's wrong, as even `docker inspect` seems correct...

```
        "Mounts": [                                                                                                                                                                                                
            {                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                "Type": "volume",                                                                                                                                                                                  
                "Name": "myvol",                                                                                                                                                        
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/myvol/_data",                                                                                                                        
                "Destination": "/app",                                                                                                                                                                             
                "Driver": "local",                                                                                                                                                                                 
                "Mode": "rw",                                                                                                                                                                                      
                "RW": true,                                                                                                                                                                                        
                "Propagation": ""                                                                                                                                                                                  
            }                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        ], 
...                                                                                                                                                                     
            "Volumes": {                                                                                                                                                                                           
                "/app": {}                                                                                                                                                                                         
            },                                                                                                                                                                                                     
            "WorkingDir": "/app",                                                                                                                                                                                  
            "Entrypoint": [                                                                                                                                                                                        
                "python",                                                                                                                                                                                          
                "main.py"                                                                                                                                                                                          
            ], 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

the `volumes` section in your compose `- myvol:/app` will overwrite the permission and all what it contains in the `/app` folder , you may delete it from your compose.

if you want to use volumes to presist data , create another mount as /app and point to it in your python code

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have fixed it.